# Grid Items keep stacking instead of creating a new row

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin

After I add a new item to a grid it goes to the same square as the last ones. When I click the button more than once instead of making a new row it makes another exercise on top of the last
[image: You can see that its bolded. Thats why i think they are overlapping]

They are overlappi on the top left square. It should create a new row with the item.

```
 private void AddExerciseToGroup()
 {
     // Create a new exercise with default values
     var newExercise = new Exercise
     {
         Reps = 0,  // Set default reps
         Weight = 0 // Set default weight
     };

     // Find the selected group based on the selected exercise type
     var selectedGroup = ExerciseTypeGroups.FirstOrDefault(group => group.ExerciseType == SelectedExerciseType);

     // Check if the selected group exists
     if (selectedGroup != null)
     {
         // Add the new exercise to the group's ExercisesInGroup collection
         selectedGroup.ExercisesInGroup.Add(newExercise);
     }
     else
     {
         // If the selected group doesn't exist, create a new group and add the exercise
         var newGroup = new ExerciseTypeGroup
         {
             ExerciseType = SelectedExerciseType,
             ExercisesInGroup = new ObservableCollection<Exercise> { newExercise }
         };

         // Add the new group to the ExerciseTypeGroups collection
         ExerciseTypeGroups.Add(newGroup);
     }

 }
```

```
<ViewCell>
 <!-- Display ExerciseType of the group -->
 <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,0"
              x:Name="ExerciseStack">
     
     <Label Text="{Binding ExerciseType.Name}" FontSize="25" Padding="10" />
        
     
         <Grid x:Name="ExerciseGrid" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ExercisesInGroup}">
             
 
             <!-- Entry for Reps -->
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
             <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <!-- Entry for Reps -->
         <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Reps" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding Exercise.Reps}" />

         <!-- Entry for Volume -->
         <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="Volume" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding Exercise.Weight}" />

         <!-- Button to add exercise to the group -->
         <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Complete" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModels:WorkoutViewModel}}, Path=CompleteExerciseCommand}" />
     </Grid>
     <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Add Exercise" Command="{Binding BindingContext.AddExerciseToGroupCommand, Source={x:Reference Workouts}}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
 </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: What specifically is overlapping?  Its not obvious from the image.  Are you placing every new element in a unique row/column?

Comment: @Jason When I click the button more than once instead of making a new row it makes another exercise on top of the last

Comment: you didn't share the code of `AddExerciseToGroupCommand` we cannot guess what is your logic

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create the new row on the top of the list?

Comment: My bad the code behind is added now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify row and col values when adding to a grid, otherwise they default to 0,0.  This is difficult to accomplish when using a bindable Grid, and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) specifically recommend not using BindableLayout with a Grid

Comment: is it a good idea to make a stack layout which  has a grid with only one row and 3 columns instead

Comment: You could do that, or use a CollectionView